# how to get the source document of a subscription odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I was creating a quotation from code and have the id of that quotation how to get the id of the assorted subscription the oder has the subscription counter at (1)

the counter has this action in odoo

```
def _compute_subscription_count(self):
        """Compute the number of distinct subscriptions linked to the order."""
        for order in self:
            sub_count = len(self.env['sale.order.line'].read_group([('order_id', '=', order.id), ('subscription_id', '!=', False)],
                                                    ['subscription_id'], ['subscription_id']))
            order.subscription_count = sub_count


def action_open_subscriptions(self):
        """Display the linked subscription and adapt the view to the number of records to display."""
        self.ensure_one()
        subscriptions = self.order_line.mapped('subscription_id')
        action = self.env.ref('sale_subscription.sale_subscription_action').read()[0]
        if len(subscriptions) > 1:
            action['domain'] = [('id', 'in', subscriptions.ids)]
        elif len(subscriptions) == 1:
            form_view = [(self.env.ref('sale_subscription.sale_subscription_view_form').id, 'form')]
            if 'views' in action:
                action['views'] = form_view + [(state,view) for state,view in action['views'] if view != 'form']
            else:
                action['views'] = form_view
            action['res_id'] = subscriptions.ids[0]
        else:
            action = {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
        action['context'] = dict(self._context, create=False)
        return action
```

I think `sub_count` without `len` is the answer but I don't understand it

can you please help

Answer (score 1):

First of all subscription is created when sale order is confirmed.
If you do this via code than you have to confirm sale order via code.
when you confirm that sale order automatically subscription is created.

Odoo base count from sale order lone have subscription_id field you have to set created id of subscription on sale order line.

for more details please check link.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/subscriptions.html

Comment: Hi uday patel, the confirmation happens by the user on the portal (sign and pay)